# Why is UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES error with com.typesafe.slick#slick_2.11;2.0.2: not found?

Tags: scala, sbt, slick

I m trying to run hello slick example from the typesafe activator I create a project in sbt when I type run it gives me following error

```
warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.slick#slick_2.11;2.0.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.slick#slick_2.11;2.0.2: not found
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Aug 25, 2014 12:20:42 AM
```

here is my build.sbt file

```
name :="hellos"

version :="1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

mainClass in Compile := Some("HelloSlick")

libraryDependencies ++= List(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.2",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.170"
)
```

I m using ubuntu 12.04 and on slick website there is no jar file is present to download so like its not in my system path variable like java and akka is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the resolver to the typesafe repository:

```
libraryDependencies ++= List(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.2",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.170"
)

resolvers += "typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

Edit:

It seems that for scala 2.11 you need to specify the slick version to be 2.1:

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0"
```

Comment: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.slick#slick_2.11;2.0.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.slick#slick_2.11;2.0.2: not found
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed Aug 25, 2014 12:45:16 AM

Comment: You are right, doesn't seems like it depends on the resolver, strange enough it's working for me. Can you try to clean and then update?

Comment: ok thanks its working now can u please tell me how u figured it out that for scala 2.11 slick 2.1 version is used ??

Comment: I'm using Slick 2.0.X on scala 2.10.4 and I guessed that the new slick version was not available for older version than scala 2.11, even now though I'm not sure, it's not explicitly stated on the [documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/introduction.html#compatibility-policy), let's call it luck :D

Comment: Here is how: 2.0.2 is in http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.slick/slick_2.10 but not in http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.slick/slick_2.11