# Unresolved slick dependency on Scala 2.11.9

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, slick

Similarly to:

[Why is UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES error with com.typesafe.slick#slick_2.11;2.0.2: not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475514/why-is-unresolved-dependencies-error-with-com-typesafe-slickslick-2-112-0-2-n)

I got the next error message:

```
events/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.slick#slick-extensions_2.11;3.1.0: not found
```

My scala build.sbt has:

```
lazy val events = (project in file("modules/events")).settings(commonSettings).
    settings(Seq(libraryDependencies ++= Seq( 
      cache,
      ws,
      evolutions,
      specs2,
      "com.softwaremill.macwire" %% "macros" % "2.2.5" % "provided",
      "com.softwaremill.macwire" %% "util" % "2.2.0",  
      "ch.qos.logback"  %  "logback-classic"   % "1.1.8",
      "de.svenkubiak" % "jBCrypt" % "0.4.1",
      "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.0" % "test",
      "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.0.45-beta" % "test",
      "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34",
      "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1207.jre7",
      "com.vividsolutions" % "jts" % "1.13",
      "com.typesafe.play" % "play-slick_2.11" % "2.0.2",
      "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.0",
      "com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg" % "0.12.1",
      "com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg_date2" % "0.12.1",
      "com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg_play-json" % "0.12.1",
      "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-extensions" % "3.1.0",
      "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc" % "2.4.2",
      "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc-config" % "2.4.2",
      "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.4",
      "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.5.9",
      "io.circe"          %% "circe-core"        % circeVersion,
      "io.circe"          %% "circe-generic"     % circeVersion,
      "io.circe"          %% "circe-parser"      % circeVersion,
      "io.circe"          %% "circe-jawn"        % circeVersion,
      "com.github.julien-truffaut" %%  "monocle-core"  % monocleVersion,
      "com.github.julien-truffaut" %%  "monocle-macro" % monocleVersion,
      "com.github.julien-truffaut" %%  "monocle-law"   % monocleVersion % "test",
      "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "7.4.1.jre8"
    )))
```

I am also using Scala 2.11.9. I also tried adding

```
resolvers += "typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

but no luck. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2):

Actually `slick-extensions` is not located in `http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/`. If you will look there you will see that `com/typesafe/slick/slick-extensions_2.11/` is empty.

But I have found it here `https://typesafe.bintray.com/commercial-maven-releases/com/typesafe/slick/slick-extensions_2.11/3.1.0/`

And here some information about `slick-extensions`: `https://index.scala-lang.org/slick/slick/slick-extensions/3.1.0`.
They recommend using that:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-extensions" % "3.1.0"
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("typesafe", "commercial-maven-releases")
```

Comment: I am getting a bad gateway with https://typesafe.bintray.com/commercial-maven-releases/com/typesafe/slick/slick-extensions_2.11/3.1.0/

Comment: Adding resolver solved the issue. Thanks!